# What is the difference between * and ** multiplication in R?

Tags: r

can anyone please help me understand what is the difference between a simple (*) multiplication and a double-asterisk (**) multiplication in R programming language?

```
x <- runif (10)
x*2
x**2
```

Comment: In R you can obtain help for questions like this by using th `?` command such as ` ?`*``  You need backticks around `*` because it's an operator.

Comment: You should Test with simple numbers :-)

Answer (score 7):

As reported in the note section of the [R Documentation of Arithmetic Operators](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html) (you ca open it executing in R the commands `help('**')` or `?'**'`) :

> ** is translated in the parser to ^, but this was undocumented for many years. It appears as an index entry in Becker et al (1988), pointing to the help for Deprecated but is not actually mentioned on that page. Even though it had been deprecated in S for 20 years, it was still accepted in R in 2008.

So basically `**` behaves exactly like `^`

Answer (score 5):

The first is multiplication, the second exponentiation:

```
> 2*3
[1] 6
> 2**3
[1] 8
```